monaco-editor keeps loading if await is used in Next JS
I'm very new to NextJs and React. I'm trying to use monaco editor in one of my page.
It works well if I use this code
"use client"

import { getCode } from '@/lib/getTasks';
import Editor from '@monaco-editor/react';


const AppDetails = async ({ params }) => {
    // console.log(params)
    // const code = await getCode(params.taskid)
    // console.log(code)
    const code = "sample code"
    return (
        <div><Editor height="90vh" defaultLanguage="python" defaultValue={code} />;</div>
    )
}

export default AppDetails

But If I use an await function
"use client"

import { getCode } from '@/lib/getTasks';
import Editor from '@monaco-editor/react';


const AppDetails = async ({ params }) => {
    console.log(params)
    const code = await getCode(params.taskid)
    console.log(code)
    return (
        <div><Editor height="90vh" defaultLanguage="python" defaultValue={code} />;</div>
    )
}

export default AppDetails

The editor only showing Loading text. I can see the correct values being fetched using console.log
Expecting my editor to load the text

 client components cannot be async functions.

Why can't Client Components be async functions?
We strongly considered supporting not only async Server Components,
but async Client Components, too. It's technically possible, but there
are enough pitfalls and caveats involved that, as of now, we aren't
comfortable with the pattern as a general recommendation. The plan is
to implement support for async Client Components in the runtime, but
log a warning during development. The documentation will also
discourage their use.
The main reason we're discouraging async Client Components is because
it's too easy for a single prop to flow through the component and
invalidate its memoization, triggering the microtask dance described
in an earlier section. It's not so much that it introduces new
performance caveats, but it makes all the performance caveats
described above much more likely.
There is one pattern where we think async Client Components make
sense: if you structure them in such a way that they're guaranteed to
only update during navigations. But the only realistic way to
guarantee this in practice is by integrating support directly into
your application's router. So it's unclear to what extent this pattern
will even be documented. At least for now.
In the future, we could unlock general support for async Client
Components by compiling them to a specialized, generator-like runtime.

